# Doing a secondary sort by year in a SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I have a table that with ID values and dates that looks something like this:

```
ID           Date
0001         1/1/2012
0002         1/2/2010
0002         1/2/2011
0001         1/1/2011
0001         1/1/2010
0002         1/2/2012
```

Basically, the ID values are unique to that year only - they reset the subsequent year.

I want to be able to sort by ID values and by dates, but I want to do the sorting so that the values are ordered by year. Just a regular sort of ID with a secondary date sort yields this:

```
ID           Date
0001         1/1/2010
0001         1/1/2011
0001         1/1/2012
0002         1/2/2010
0002         1/2/2011
0002         1/2/2012
```

But I would like a query that generates a table that looks like this:

```
ID           Date
0001         1/1/2010
0002         1/2/2010
0001         1/1/2011
0002         1/2/2011
0001         1/1/2012
0002         1/2/2012
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about this:

```
order by year(date), id
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM .. ORDER BY DATEPART("yyyy",myDateColumn), ID

Comment: Oh, yes, I forgot the quotes around the "yy" - I've updated now. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: I've just run the following SQL in the sample Access Issues database installed with Access 2010 database

SELECT DatePart("yy",DueDate) FROM Issues;

It worked.

Comment: I have never been able to find "yy" in any Access documentation. If it worked that is new to me. Sorry about that

Comment: @OverMind actually, for the record, I think you are right. The query compiled and executed, but did indeed fail if there were matching rows. You are correct - the format which works is "yyyy" - I've corrected my original response. Thanks for the correction ... again.

Comment: No problem! Just trying to help