# Sorting records on a form in MS Access 2010

Tags: ms-access

I had a question last week about how to do a sort of ascending ID numbers by year for a SQL query.

[Doing a secondary sort by year in a SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25529773/doing-a-secondary-sort-by-year-in-a-sql-query/)

I followed those instructions and the result was great for my table. The data in the resultant query was used to create a table that was then linked to a form. Unfortunately, as I add new records to the table, am I seeing that the sort is not respected after data entry (that is, new records are automatically displayed first when browsing records with the form instead of last). Is there a way to do a sort with ascending ID numbers and year within the form itself? When I try to use the ORDER BY year (date) expression in the form properties I'm getting an "undefined function in expression" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already create a new table from the data, you could add a new column to that table containing the "year(date)" result. That way, you have a real column you can ORDER BY on. (ORDER BY yearcol, id)

When inserting, fill it with the current year.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, though in the end I did not need to do this. For some reason using the YEAR function works now. I'm honestly not sure what was going on before.